# rails4 migration for a column of two dimensional arrays to postgres

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, multidimensional-array, migration

What is the correct syntax in a migration to create a column capable of storing two dimensional arrays in postgres with rails4? I know how to do a single dimensional column

```
t.float :vami, array: true, default: []
```

but not sure how to do multidimensional. Some of the tutorials on using arrays seem to suggest it's possible, but they don't outline how to specify it in the migration. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can, I'm pretty sure a two dimensional array will just confuse ActiveRecord at each step. You could store it flattened and un-flatten it as needed though.

Comment: PostgreSQL arrays are more like matrices - they aren't arrays of arrays, but true multidimensional arrays. This is often very annoying, and rarely beneficial, but that's how it is. So they don't map wonderfully to Rails arrays and vice versa. Plus, as Mu says - Rails will probably get very confused.